# In django, use django-dbbackup and django-crontab to backup automatically

Tags: django, amazon-s3, backup, django-cron

I'm use django-bdbackup and django-storage backup my db into aws s3, fortunately it work.

In the next step, I want to it backup automatically, but it's not lucky this time.

I add two things in SETTINGS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
...
...
'django_crontab',
...
...
...
]
```

and

```
CRONJOBS = [
('*/1 * * * *', 'django.core.management.call_command', ['dbbackup'],{'-o':'2020-07/dbbackup_20200801.7z'})
]
```

It's not work.There are nothing in my s3 bucket, and no message appeared.

Can anyone tell me what I wrong or something I miss?

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py crontab add`?

Comment: Idk, but I try it tomorrow and it work.